# vlc and launcher

Tags: 14.04, unity, bash, launcher, vlc

I tried to add an entry to the contextual menu of the ubuntu launcher to be able to start .part files in the download folder.
This is how it looks like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=VLC media player
GenericName=Media player
Comment=Read, capture, broadcast your multimedia streams
Icon=vlc
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=AudioVideo;Player;Recorder;
Exec=vlc
MimeType=...
X-KDE-Protocols=ftp,http,https,mms,rtmp,rtsp,sftp,smb
Keywords=Player;Capture;DVD;Audio;Video;Server;Broadcast;

Actions=OpenParts;
[Desktop Action OpenParts]
Exec=sh -c "vlc /home/me/Downloads/*.part"
Name=Open all .part files in Download folder
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

However now it seems I can't open multiple files in one instance, it instead opens multiple instances.
What I would like is the following:

- ability to have multiple vlc instances
- if I open multiple vlc files at once from the file manager, just open one new instance with all the files selected

Answer (score 1):

The easiest  way to solve this would  be to go into vlc click the tools menu then preferences check the `allow only one instance` and `use only one instance when starting form file manager` and that should take care of your problem

Comment: I still want to be able to open multiple instances, as said above, and if I check 'allow only one instance', wouldn't that prevent me from opening multiple instances?

Comment: sorry im tried must have overlooked that :(

Comment: You're probably right in that it shouldn't be too difficult, probably a couple of options and right command line arguments, I had it working before, but I broke it by changing this configuration file, it seems.